# How to switch to master, when there is no master

Tags: git

I have built a website with git and from the beginning I have done no work in the master branch, which is now empty. I started out with:

```
$ git checkout -b dev_project
```

and have done all my development in that branch. I thought it would be good to use the master branch as a release branch, but I can see that locally I don't have that branch.

```
c:/wamp/www>git branch
8.0.x. (my drupal branch)
dev_project (my project branch)
```

So how can I merge dev_project HEAD into master?

Comment: The default branch name in Git is master. If you type 'git branch' don't you see master?

Comment: I know that is the default branch, but locally when I type git branch I don't see master. Which made me post this question :-)

Comment: do you see a master branch when you do a 'git branch -a'? (this shows branches in all your remotes)

Comment: D J: Nope, but it seems that the solution is to ceate the master branch locally, as suggested byt the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the branch master:

```
git branch master dev_project
```

You don't have anything to merge. Master will actually **diverge** from dev_project. That seems weird but it's actually what you want to do.

Continue working on dev_project, and when you want to release merge it into master, issuing:

```
git checkout master
git merge dev_project
```

Answer (score 1):

A branch is nothing more or less than a pointer to a commit in `git`. Since you have not created a master branch yet, there simply is no such pointer as there is nothing it could point to.
You can start your release branch by simply calling

```
git branch master
```

This creates the pointer and points it to the current commit. After that, you can just keep working on your feature branches, and merge with `master` as you please.

However, I would suggest using tags to mark releases: A branch is a dynamic entity by design, and from the commit history there is nothing that connects a given commit to any branch (it's the branch that references the commit, not the other way round). As such, if you only use your master branch to publish versions, you won't be able to find earlier versions again. The tag, by contrast, is a fixed entity, which is meant to be used to mark releases.

Comment: cmaster: In my github repo there is a master branch, but I don't have it locally. Can I still checkout master locally? I shouldn't do git fetch all or somehting like that to retrieve the master branch from Github?

Comment: cmaster: I thought that I would merge with master and also set a release tag. That way I can find earlier versions, but only on the master branch.

Comment: @TBJ What output do you get when you call `git branch -a`? Do you see a line `remotes/origin/master`? If not, does it appear after you perform a `git fetch`? If that is the case, then yes, you need to checkout the upstream `master` (`git checkout master` should do), merge your feature branch, and then push the result.

Comment: cmaster: Thanks for your answer. The problem is solved. I checked out the master branch, made a pull (to get the readme file from the remote master branch, which was the only file on that branch). After that I made git add -A locally, and pushed my local master branch to my repo at Github. I also added a release tag locally and pushed that too. So now my remote master contains my first release version and also a tag.